# Get request information in PhantomJS using Codeception

Tags: phantomjs, codeception

Is there a way during the acceptance test, to get information about all request that page made?
I want to check if page sends good tracking information via JavaScript Code (not .gif).
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt there is any way to do this, unless one of the driver's has an API I don't know about. You'll have to use some other method. Here is a good discussion:
[Accessing the web page's HTTP Headers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript)

I'd sugggest re-thinking the test. Is there a way to mock the page request and just test the tracking?